# Using office365-REST-Python-Client to list all the files and folders from Document Library, but I can only see Folders but not files

Tags: python, office365api

I used below Python code to list all the files and folders from Documents Library, but I can only see folders but not files. It never have any case when `item.file_system_object_type == 0`, but I can see there are a lot of files under Document Library.

What're the possible root causes? Thought it's the permission issue, but I'm the owner of the site.

==========================================

```
doc_lib = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title("Documents")
items = doc_lib.items.select(["FileSystemObjectType"]).expand(["File", "Folder"]).get().execute_query()
for item in items: # type: ListItem
if item.file_system_object_type == 1:
print("Folder url: {0}".format(item.folder.serverRelativeUrl))
else:
print("File url: {0}".format(item.file.serverRelativeUrl))
```

I used the same code, I can see both folders and files from another site within the organization intranet. So was wondering where I am missing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please format your code.